# rclpy.action.ActionServer callback 'goal_handle' type

Tags: ros, rclpy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
When opening an action server it looks something like this:

```
self.move_up_action_server = ActionServer(self, MoveVerticalAction, 'move_vertical', self.move_up_callback)
```

With the callback being:

```
def move_up_callback(self, goal_handle):
```

I couldn't find anywhere what is the type of `goal_handle`.
Seems like it has `goal_handle.request`, `goal_handle.publish_feedback`, `goal_handle.succeed`. Maybe some of you know what is the python type I should use?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/415682/rclpy.action.actionserver-callback-%27goal_handle%27-type/) by [Erel](https://answers.ros.org/users/149313/erel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2023-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok I realized I was stupid.
I just used python's `type()` and found out it is `rclpy.action.server.ServerGoalHandle`.
Problem solved.

---

Originally posted by [Erel](https://answers.ros.org/users/149313/erel/) with karma: 16 on 2023-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0